# Toggle Spelling & Grammar programatically in Word (Microsoft Office)

Tags: vba, ms-word

It would help if there is a way to toggle the underlining on and off programmatically, assigning the command to a button to enable me to toggle with a single click.

It is a pain to go through the menus every time I want to do it currently.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Create two macros. One to turn on and one to turn off Spelling and Grammar as you type.

In Microsoft software, you are able to record a sequence of actions and assign them to a button or keyboard shortcut

Follow these steps precisely to create the ones specific to this solution.

**Macro 1: Spelling off**

1. Click View > Macros > Record macro
2. Type "spelling_off" into the Macro name field (Spaces aren't permitted so use underscore _ character) and click the hammer button.
3. Click 'Normal.NewMacros.spelling_off' and then the 'Add >>' button
4. Click 'Modify...' and choose a graphic and click OK. (I choose the red square)
5. Click OK in the Word Options screen.
6. Click Review > Language > Language preferences > Proofing
7. Uncheck 'Check spelling as you type'
8. Uncheck 'Mark grammar as you type'
9. Click OK
10. Click View > Macros > Stop Recording

The macro code will look like this:

```
Sub spelling_off()
'
' spelling_off Macro
'
'
    Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType = False

    Options.CheckSpellingAsYouType = False

    Application.ScreenRefresh

End Sub
```

**Macro 2: Spelling on**

1. Click View > Macros > Record macro
2. Type "spelling_on" into the Macro name field and click the MC Hammer button.
3. Click 'Normal.NewMacros.spelling_on' and then the 'Add >>' button
4. Click 'Modify...' and choose a graphic and click OK. (I choose the green square)
5. Click OK in the Word Options screen.
6. Click Review > Language > Language preferences > Proofing
7. Check 'Check spelling as you type'
8. Check 'Mark grammar as you type'
9. Click OK
10. Click View > Macros > Stop Recording

The macro code will look like this:

```
Sub spelling_on()
'
' spelling_on Macro
'
'
    Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType = True

    Options.CheckSpellingAsYouType = True

    Application.ScreenRefresh

End Sub
```

...and that's it!

**Where do the buttons appear?**

The buttons appear in the top left hand corner of Microsoft Word.